# smart pointers with POD Structures and inheritance

Tags: c++11, inheritance, struct, smart-pointers

I am developing an application that uses POD C++ structures.  This was working fine until I needed to have 2 variants of a one of my POD structs.   Introducing virtual inheritance (due to the presence of the virtual destructor in the base class) in order to manage these similar POD structures in a polymorphic manner (as they share common base fields) changes the overall size of the derived data structures – as it needs to accommodate the vtable.    Not having a virtual base class on the other hand introduces data slicing during smart pointer destructors.

Is there some way around this such that I can maintain the ease of managing these PODS through their base class while not introducing data slicing/memory leaks when the std::unique_ptr’s destructors get called.

I put together a simple [**live coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c031fa68ff7bba8d) demo showing the various aspects of the POD structs I encountered, unfortunately I do not know how to contain these in vector of virtual base unique pointers.  Any help/design pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
struct VBase {
    uint32_t mBaseInt;

    // allow default construction using placement operator
    VBase() = default;

    // copy constructor
    VBase(const VBase&) = default;

    // move constructor
    VBase(VBase&&) = default;

    // explicit constructor
    explicit VBase(const uint32_t val) 
        : mBaseInt(val)
    {
        std::cout << "VBase(val)" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~VBase() = default;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct Derived1 : VBase {
    uint32_t mDerivedInt;

    // allow default construction using placement operator
    Derived1() = default;

    // copy constructor
    Derived1(const Derived1&) = default;

    // move constructor
    Derived1(Derived1&&) = default;

    // explicit constructor
    explicit Derived1(const uint32_t val, const uint32_t val1) 
        : VBase(val)
        , mDerivedInt(val1)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived1(val, val1)" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Derived1() {
        std::cout << "~Derived1()" << std::endl;
    };
} __attribute__((packed));

struct Derived2 : VBase {
    uint32_t mDerivedInt1;
    uint32_t mDerivedInt2;

    // allow default construction using placement operator
    Derived2() = default;

    // copy constructor
    Derived2(const Derived2&) = default;

    // move constructor
    Derived2(Derived2&&) = default;

    // explicit constructor
    explicit Derived2(
        const uint32_t val, 
        const uint32_t val1, 
        const uint32_t val2) 
        : VBase(val)
        , mDerivedInt1(val1)
        , mDerivedInt2(val2)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived2(val, val1, val2)" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~Derived2() {
        std::cout << "~Derived2()" << std::endl;
    };
} __attribute__((packed));

struct NVBase {
    explicit NVBase() {
        std::cout << " NVBase()" << std::endl;
    }
    ~NVBase() {
        std::cout << "~NVBase()" << std::endl;
    };
} __attribute__((packed));

struct D : NVBase {
    uint16_t f;
    explicit D() 
        : NVBase()
    {}

    ~D() {
        std::cout << "~D()" << std::endl;
    };
} __attribute__((packed));

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words = {
        "Hello", "from", "GCC", __VERSION__, "!"
    };
    std::cout << words << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(VBase)=" << sizeof(VBase) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(Derived1)=" << sizeof(Derived1) <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(Derived2)=" << sizeof(Derived2)<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(NVBase)=" << sizeof(NVBase) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(D)=" << sizeof(D) << std::endl;
    std::unique_ptr<VBase> pVBase = std::make_unique<Derived1>(1,2);
    std::unique_ptr<NVBase> pNVDerived = std::make_unique<D>();
    std::cout << sizeof(*pVBase) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(*pNVDerived) << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<VBase>> vec = {
        //std::make_unique<Derived1>(1,2)
    };
   // vec.emplace_back(std::move(*pVBase));
}
```

Comment: Instead of using virtual inheritance, you might want to look into `boost::variant` instead. You could declare a variant type, which takes one of two POD types as its value. Then use that where you would have used the virtual base class. This may have performance benefits over doing virtual dispatch anyways, and it doesn't mess up the PODness of your structures. (Don't have to use `boost::variant`, could use another implementation of variant, or role your own simple "tagged union".)

Comment: @ChrisBeck interesting suggestion, can this me made to work with unique_ptrs, so unique_ptr<variant<POD1, POD2>>?  or something along those lines?  I have not used variants before, I just started reading about these and any's (although these are not part of stl yet)

Comment: Yes. A `variant` is a "value type", not some kind of pointer type. If you have two POD types, then in particular, they exist entirely on the stack if you declare as a local variable in a function. A variant based off of them then also exists entirely on the stack if it is declared as a local variable in a function. `variant` is not POD, and it's not a "trivial" class -- it's destructor will call the dtor of the contained object, unlike a `union`. But it is "standard layout" iirc. You could have `unique_ptr<variant<POD1, POD2>>` just as easily as `unique_ptr<POD1>` or `unique_ptr<int>`.

Comment: How exactly do you plan to use these structs "in a polymorphic manner", considering they don't have any virtual functions besides the destructor? Why do their sizes matter? The ultimate goal of the exercise remains unclear to me. Also, as a point of terminology, none of your structs are *POD-structs* within the meaning of the standard; I'm not sure what you mean by the term `POD`.

Comment: Maybe this would help: unlike `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` destroys the object correctly when upcasting to base type. That is, this is legal even when `Base` has a non-virtual destructor: `shared_ptr<Derived> pD(new Derived()); shared_ptr<Base> pB(pD); pD.reset(); pB.reset();` Even though the object is being destroyed by an instance of `shared_ptr<Base>`, the `Derived` destructor is called correctly. The trick is that the deleter is captured at the point of construction and stored in the control block, together with the reference count.